# how to use a frame with absolute layout to create a pop up window on top of a grid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am building an app that has a grid which contains many buttons and entries. When you click on one of the buttons on the grid i want to have a pop up window so that the user can take some actions in there. I've gotten this to almost work by using an absolute layout along with a frame plus other views inside the frame. My only issue is that when the frame appears after clicking on the pop up button, the other components of the grid are still active behind the frame and can be clicked on.

For example, i have an entry to enter a note. When the pop up appears, it covers the Notes entry, **BUT** if you click on just the right spot, you can still get the entry for the Notes to come up and enter data in there. it's very weird.
I know that i can just disable all of the other buttons and entries in the grid when the user clicks on the popup button, but i was wondering if there was an easier/better way of doing this that i'm missing rather than manually disabling/enabling the buttons every time the popup window comes up. Thank you

Comment: you might try using the InputTransparent property - otherwise it's difficult to provide specific help because you have not posted any of your code or xaml.  You might also look at the popup control in Xamarin Community Toolkit

Comment: You can add a full size BoxView before your popup in the Grid to avoid the click and `BackgroundColor = "transparent"`

Comment: just gave this a try, and unfortunately even when putting the boxview on top of the grid before the pop up the buttons are still active. i can't see them really because of the boxview, but i can still click on their locations and enter data on them. such a weird behavior. it's starting to look like the only workaround will be to manually disable them when the pop up appears.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can make a full size pop up window on top of a grid.

I made a simple demo, and it works properly. When I clicked the `Show Popup` button, a popup window will pop up. We can make the popup area fill the screen and set `BackgroundColor` to transparent color(`#C0808080`).

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Azure" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                <Label Text="Test " HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium"></Label>
                <Image x:Name="imgFruit" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200" Source="cherry.png"></Image>
                <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="btnPopupButton_Clicked" Text="Show Popup"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--Popup Area-->
        <ContentView x:Name="popupLoginView" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Entry Margin="20,20,20,10" Placeholder="Enter Username"></Entry>
                    <Entry Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Enter Password"></Entry>
                    <Button Margin="20,0,20,0" Text="Login"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Function `btnPopupButton_Clicked`

```
    private void btnPopupButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        popupLoginView.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: i appreciate the comment and the piece of code is great, but it doesn't really answer my question. Your pop up still has the same issue as my pop up which is the buttons on the grid behind are still active and if you tap them you can enter data on them. that's what i was trying to find a workaround for instead of having to manually disable the buttons when the pop up appears. any ideas for that? thank you

Comment: But you cannot click "show popup" in this one, right? @gio13

Comment: @gio13,we  couldn't tap the Button in the behind after the pop up window displaying since the pop-up area (`ContentView`) is full screen.